# Writing the inclusion relation on the power set $P(\{a,b,c\})$ in matrix notation.

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

Here is the question. As far as I know, I understand what a power set is, but the last half of the question confused me, and I have no idea what it means.

> Write the inclusion relation on the power set $P(\{a,b,c\})$, namely $$(X,Y)\in R \quad\text{iff}\quad X \subseteq Y$$
> in the matrix notation.

Comment: The best I can think of is : form a graph , whose vertices are the elements of $P(\{a,b,c\})$, and where $X \to Y$ is a directed edge if $X \subset Y$. Then the adjacency matrix of this graph is being asked for, by the question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon that is, sounds reasonable.

Comment: Then I think you can write an answer mentioning that.

Comment: I tried, but it looks bizarre...

Comment: I have done it, you can see below.

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt is off, I am not sure what you are doing.

For the answer, the graph is created by the vertices being the subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$ and two subsets being directly connected if the former is a subset of the latter. Therefore, we take our vertex set in the order : $\{\emptyset , \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\}, \{a,b,c\}\}$. So the row for $\{a\}$ will look like $[0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]$ because that is the subsets which contain $a$ according to our order. Therefore , creating the matrix gives :
$$
\color{red}{
\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1&1&1&1&1&1 \\
0&1&0&0&1&1&0&1 \\
0&0&1&0&1&0&1&1 \\
0&0&0&1&0&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}}
$$

which looks correct and beautiful as well.